# How can I get the "Terminating" status in io.fabric8.kubernetes-client

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

For some reasons, Pod [itom-itsma-backup-deployment-989867dc5-9w84b] is stuck in Terminating status. I have a Java client to monitor the Pod status using **io.fabric8.kubernetes-client**
[image]
Java code like below:

```
List<Pod> pods = client.pods().inNamespace(namespace).list().getItems();
```

But it returns the response like below.

status.phase is "Running" & status.containerStatuses.ready is "false"

I think the phase is not correct. It should be "Terminating".
Get the same result if I use "kubectl get pod itom-itsma-backup-deployment-989867dc5-9w84b -n itsma1 -o yaml"

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2018-08-20T07:58:16Z",
        "deletionGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "deletionTimestamp": "2018-08-27T04:00:22Z",
        "finalizers": [],
        "generateName": "itom-itsma-backup-deployment-989867dc5-",
        "labels": {
            "app": "itom-itsma-backup",
            "itsmaRelease": "2018.05",
            "itsmaService": "itom-itsma-backup",
            "name": "itom-itsma-backup-pod",
            "pod-template-hash": "545423871"
        },
        "name": "itom-itsma-backup-deployment-989867dc5-9w84b",
        "namespace": "itsma1",
        "ownerReferences": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
                "kind": "ReplicaSet",
                "blockOwnerDeletion": true,
                "controller": true,
                "name": "itom-itsma-backup-deployment-989867dc5",
                "uid": "cba0ffdf-a44e-11e8-8740-005056b02030"
            }
        ],
        "resourceVersion": "1056727",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/itsma1/pods/itom-itsma-backup-deployment-989867dc5-9w84b",
        "uid": "cba3627a-a44e-11e8-8740-005056b02030"
    },
    "spec": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "args": [],
                "command": [],
                "env": [
                    {
                        "name": "SUITE_TIME_ZONE",
                        "value": "Asia/Shanghai"
                    }
                ],
                "envFrom": [],
                "image": "shc-harbor-dev.hpeswlab.net/itsma/itom-itsma-backup:0.0.35",
                "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                "livenessProbe": {
                    "failureThreshold": 6,
                    "httpGet": {
                        "httpHeaders": [],
                        "path": "/health",
                        "port": 8081,
                        "scheme": "HTTP"
                    },
                    "initialDelaySeconds": 180,
                    "periodSeconds": 30,
                    "successThreshold": 1,
                    "timeoutSeconds": 10
                },
                "name": "itom-itsma-backup-pod",
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "containerPort": 8081,
                        "name": "backend-port",
                        "protocol": "TCP"
                    }
                ],
                "readinessProbe": {
                    "exec": {
                        "command": [
                            "/bin/sh",
                            "/app/healthz.sh"
                        ]
                    },
                    "failureThreshold": 3,
                    "initialDelaySeconds": 30,
                    "periodSeconds": 10,
                    "successThreshold": 2,
                    "timeoutSeconds": 10
                },
                "resources": {
                    "limits": {
                        "cpu": "2",
                        "memory": "2Gi"
                    },
                    "requests": {
                        "cpu": "300m",
                        "memory": "512Mi"
                    }
                },
                "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                "volumeMounts": [
                    {
                        "mountPath": "/app/backup-service/global-volume",
                        "name": "backup-global-volume"
                    },
                    {
                        "mountPath": "/app/backup-service/db-volume",
                        "name": "backup-db-volume"
                    },
                    {
                        "mountPath": "/app/backup-service/smartanalytics-volume",
                        "name": "backup-smartanalytics-volume"
                    },
                    {
                        "mountPath": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount",
                        "name": "default-token-4w6dp",
                        "readOnly": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "hostAliases": [],
        "imagePullSecrets": [
            {
                "name": "registrypullsecret"
            }
        ],
        "initContainers": [],
        "nodeName": "shc-sma-cd77.hpeswlab.net",
        "nodeSelector": {
            "Worker": "label"
        },
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
        "securityContext": {
            "supplementalGroups": []
        },
        "serviceAccount": "default",
        "serviceAccountName": "default",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "tolerations": [
            {
                "effect": "NoExecute",
                "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready",
                "operator": "Exists",
                "tolerationSeconds": 300
            },
            {
                "effect": "NoExecute",
                "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
                "operator": "Exists",
                "tolerationSeconds": 300
            }
        ],
        "volumes": [
            {
                "name": "backup-global-volume",
                "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                    "claimName": "global-volume"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "backup-db-volume",
                "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                    "claimName": "db-volume"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "backup-smartanalytics-volume",
                "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                    "claimName": "smartanalytics-volume"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "default-token-4w6dp",
                "secret": {
                    "defaultMode": 420,
                    "items": [],
                    "secretName": "default-token-4w6dp"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": {
        "conditions": [
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2018-08-20T07:58:16Z",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "Initialized"
            },
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2018-08-27T03:58:47Z",
                "message": "containers with unready status: [itom-itsma-backup-pod]",
                "reason": "ContainersNotReady",
                "status": "False",
                "type": "Ready"
            },
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2018-08-20T07:58:16Z",
                "status": "True",
                "type": "PodScheduled"
            }
        ],
        "containerStatuses": [
            {
                "containerID": "docker://26108b9c62bd0833b68f3ea94a17736e1b237cc6742b4b80b42808474e990a9b",
                "image": "shc-harbor-dev.hpeswlab.net/itsma/itom-itsma-backup:0.0.35",
                "imageID": "docker-pullable://shc-harbor-dev.hpeswlab.net/itsma/itom-itsma-backup@sha256:34045745e7968730bf760264cb395ca9976154b686cc1c3128a35c44a40bd2d6",
                "lastState": {},
                "name": "itom-itsma-backup-pod",
                "ready": false,
                "restartCount": 0,
                "state": {
                    "running": {
                        "startedAt": "2018-08-20T07:59:24Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "hostIP": "15.119.88.77",
        "initContainerStatuses": [],
        "phase": "Running",
        "podIP": "172.16.79.4",
        "qosClass": "Burstable",
        "startTime": "2018-08-20T07:58:16Z"
    }
}
```

But if I use "kubectl describe pod itom-itsma-backup-deployment-989867dc5-9w84b -n itsma1" I can get the status "Terminating".

```
Name:                      itom-itsma-backup-deployment-989867dc5-9w84b
Namespace:                 itsma1
Node:                      shc-sma-cd77.hpeswlab.net/15.119.88.77
Start Time:                Mon, 20 Aug 2018 15:58:16 +0800
Labels:                    app=itom-itsma-backup
                           itsmaRelease=2018.05
                           itsmaService=itom-itsma-backup
                           name=itom-itsma-backup-pod
                           pod-template-hash=545423871
Annotations:               <none>
Status:                    Terminating (expires Mon, 27 Aug 2018 12:00:22 +0800)
Termination Grace Period:  30s
IP:                        172.16.79.4
Controlled By:             ReplicaSet/itom-itsma-backup-deployment-989867dc5
Containers:
  itom-itsma-backup-pod:
    Container ID:   docker://26108b9c62bd0833b68f3ea94a17736e1b237cc6742b4b80b42808474e990a9b
    Image:          shc-harbor-dev.hpeswlab.net/itsma/itom-itsma-backup:0.0.35
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://shc-harbor-dev.hpeswlab.net/itsma/itom-itsma-backup@sha256:34045745e7968730bf760264cb395ca9976154b686cc1c3128a35c44a40bd2d6
    Port:           8081/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 20 Aug 2018 15:59:24 +0800
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  2Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      300m
      memory:   512Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:8081/health delay=180s timeout=10s period=30s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:  exec [/bin/sh /app/healthz.sh] delay=30s timeout=10s period=10s #success=2 #failure=3
    Environment:
      SUITE_TIME_ZONE:  Asia/Shanghai
    Mounts:
      /app/backup-service/db-volume from backup-db-volume (rw)
      /app/backup-service/global-volume from backup-global-volume (rw)
      /app/backup-service/smartanalytics-volume from backup-smartanalytics-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-4w6dp (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True 
  Ready          False 
  PodScheduled   True 
Volumes:
  backup-global-volume:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  global-volume
    ReadOnly:   false
  backup-db-volume:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  db-volume
    ReadOnly:   false
  backup-smartanalytics-volume:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  smartanalytics-volume
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-4w6dp:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-4w6dp
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  Worker=label
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason   Age               From                                Message
  ----    ------   ----              ----                                -------
  Normal  Killing  1m (x51 over 1h)  kubelet, shc-sma-cd77.hpeswlab.net  Killing container with id docker://itom-itsma-backup-pod:Need to kill Pod
```

I am curious about **how can I get the "Terminating" status**? Is there a corresponding method in io.fabric8.kubernetes-client of "kubectl describe pod  [pod name]"

Comment: Hm, It looks like a bug in client, Could you please file an issue on kubernetes client also?

Comment: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/1189